# Link after visiting not clickable

Tags: html, css, layout, hyperlink, overlay

I have added an overlay dialog box to my homepage. 
When I click on the  tag the dialog box becomes visible.

The problem now is that when I close the dialog box 
the link is disabled for clicking for about 7 seconds. 
After doing nothing or clicking around it becomes enabled again.

I have created that [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hypgrrg5/) of my source code.

The Css of the overlay dialog looks like that:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 20;

}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align:left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.popup .content {
  height:95%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

In the fiddle my problem is not reconstructed. 
Even with all the other stuff the fiddle works correct
but the problem still appears at my page though the code is the same in the fiddle and on my page.

I am using a [fullPageSlider](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/) of Alvarotrigo.
Perhaps the issue has something to deal with it?

Comment: If you can't recreate the issue and aren't providing a link to the original page, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: I've tried to import the fullPageSlider in the fiddle with jQuery too but can't reproduce the error. Can you post here the link to your real page? Regards